# Best way to connect Java and Visual Studio 6 C++ via API

Tags: java, xml, windows, api, visual-c++

We have a web platform written in Java. It will expose certain functionality via some kind of an API - soap, rest or some kind of home-brewed XML. The point is that it'll expose itself via HTTP/s.

There's another stand alone application that was written in C++ (Visual Studio 6) which needs to connect to the aforementioned API. I'm not an expert in C++ so I have hard time recommending something that can accomplish the task. I'm mentioning VS6 as per request of our developer since upgrading is not on a table.

Can someone recommend some library for C++, standard or not, that can simplify API interaction between two applications? If pointed to the right direction, we'll be able to review ourselves to make final decision.

Answer (score 0):

We use [lmx](http://codalogic.com/lmx/).